# How to sent data to server, and return the output to the client?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tcp

I have to create an application for adding two numbers, using TCP socket programming. The operation must occur on the server, that accepts two numbers and returns the result. So, the solution must contain two components: the server and the client. Within the client, the user must be allowed to enter two numbers using the Scanner class. Values must be placed inside variables and then sent to the server side of the application. Values can be sent together or separately. After accepting the value, the server should add the numbers and deliver the resulting sum to the client. The amount obtained must be displayed at checkout.

Client

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80);
    BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
        bos.write("Get /search?q=java HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert number x.");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert number y.");
        int y = input.nextInt();
        bos.flush();
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Server

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Listening.");
        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1080);
             Socket s = server.accept();
             BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
             BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream())) {
            System.out.println("Connected.");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(bis.readLine());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(bis.readLine());
            int z = x + y;
            bos.write(("The amount is:" + z).getBytes());
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:781)
    at Server.main(Server.java:15)
```

What am I doing wrong? I think I got the Server part right, but I don't know how to deal with the Client.
Many thanks!

Comment: The first thing the client does is write bos.write("Get /search?q=java HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".getBytes()); and tge first thing the server does is tries to read Integer.parseInt(bis.readLine());  - so write String/read Int. Not really sure you need to sent the whole “get” string here, unless you intent to write a http server

Comment: Oh and `try (Socket socket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80);` - pretty sure that's not correct

Comment: As the exception message says the server can't deal with the misplaced HTTP header. As you're using raw TCP/IP it's not necessary. Did you try without?

Answer (score 0):

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80);
```

doesn't make sense, I'm pretty sure you're not asking Google for the answer

The first thing your client does is writes...

```
bos.write("Get /search?q=java HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
```

but the first thing your server does is reads...

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(bis.readLine());
```

So you're trying to write a `String` but read an `int`, hence the core of your issue.

Now, unless your intention is to write your own http server, you don't need to send the preamble `get ...`

I'd also make use of `BufferedWriter` over a `BufferedOutputStream`, it's just going to help make your life easier.

So, let's start by updating the `Server`...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Listening.");
        try (
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1080); Socket s = server.accept(); 
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream())); 
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()))) {
            System.out.println("Connected.");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            int z = x + y;
            bw.write("The amount is:" + z);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And now the `Client`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1080); 
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Insert number x.");
            int x = input.nextInt();
            bw.write(Integer.toString(x));
            bw.newLine();
            System.out.println("Insert number y.");
            int y = input.nextInt();
            bw.write(Integer.toString(y));
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();

            String result = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This makes an assumption that the server and client are running on the same machine, if not, then you'll need to change the `Socket` address to be the same as the computer's IP address (or host name) that the `Server` is running on.

Now, when I run it (make sure to start the `Server` first) I get...

```
Insert number x.
1
Insert number y.
1
The amount is:2
```